# SQL Operations Studio on Mac cannot connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-studio

I have a problem with SQL Operations Studio on a Mac.

SQL OS cannot connect to a MS SQL Server Database. On the bottom right, the notification "mssql not supported" pops up.

When I try to connect to a server, it'll just load endlessly.

This is not my Mac and since I don't have a Mac, I can only sparsely try things out. I would be happy for any suggestions regarding this issue.

Comment: it would be interesting to know where the SQL-Server is running (Docker Container, internal-, external- network). I assume its all about the server name and port which is wrong or missing.

Comment: The server is running on a Windows 7 Computer. The Server name and port was definitely correct. Other computers don't have a problem connecting.

Comment: If this is the case I would try to start to ping the server to check if it’s reachable from the Mac.

Comment: I already did that. Worked fine (Computer was reachable). I also have to add: The Mac is in the same network via VPN (Tunnelblick). So I don't know if that poses aproblem. (But as I said, pinging is no problem).

Comment: I still have the problem. Now on two different Macs. I don't know if it's a problem with SQL Studio or VPN. (Although pinging the server works)

Comment: Is the newer Azure Data Studio working better?

Comment: Hi @MiepMiep, did you find any solution for this problem? Now we faced same issue, We use tunnelblick for vpn and we dont connect sql server endless load. My other friends connected succesfully who are use windows machine and another vpn application.